# Google Cloud Function Python installing dependency on each request

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

**requirements.txt**:

```
pymystem3==0.2.0
```

**main.py**:

```
from pymystem3 import Mystem
import json

def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json and 'text' in request_json:
        text = request_json['text']
        m = Mystem()
        lemmas = m.lemmatize(text)

        return json.dumps(m.analyze(text), ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8', sort_keys=True, indent=2)
    else:
        return 'No text provided'
```

Logs in google cloud:

```
hello_world
032ljsdfawo
Function execution started

hello_world
032ljsdfawo
Installing mystem to /tmp/.local/bin/mystem from http://download.cdn.yandex.net/mystem/mystem-3.1-linux-64bit.tar.gz

Expand all | Collapse all {
 insertId:  "000000-a9eaa07b-d936-45d8-a186-927cc94246d6"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/project_name/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-09-26T09:41:31.070927654Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "Installing mystem to /tmp/.local/bin/mystem from http://download.cdn.yandex.net/mystem/mystem-3.1-linux-64bit.tar.gz"  
 timestamp:  "2018-09-26T09:41:19.595Z"  
}
```

I'm new to python, so it's probably a very simple mistake. Maybe dependencies suppose to be installed before deploying the function somehow and compiled with `main.py`?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to unfortunate behavior by the `pymsystem` library: instead of including everything it needs in it's Python package, it's attempting to download additional things at runtime, specifically every time you import it.

[You can see that the message in your logs is coming from the library itself](https://github.com/nlpub/pymystem3/blob/683d52908e09571dec4f9cfe9af05d550250bcbf/pymystem3/mystem.py#L71).

It seems like the library is attempting to determine if it has already been installed or not, but this might not be working correctly. I'd recommend filing an issue [on the project's issue tracker](https://github.com/nlpub/pymystem3/issues).